# Integer to std_logic type conversion

Tags: vhdl

I want to assign the value of a generic that is an integer to a signal which is a std_logic type. My generic can take only two values, `0` and `1`.

How do I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290298/convert-integer-to-std-logic

Comment: You can also use a conditional signal assignment in place of Martin Thompson's function (linked by diverger).

Answer (score 1):

Many choices here. You can use a conditional signal assignment:

```
signal a:    std_logic;
signal int:    integer range 0 to 1;

a <= '0' when int = 0 else
     '1';
```

And the integer could be class constant, and derived from a generic.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This logic worked fine actually.

Comment: You can also define CONSTANT V01 : std_logic_vector(0 TO 1):="01"; then use your generic integer to index that vector.